# ListBox in another ListBox in Firemonkey Style Designer

Tags: delphi, listbox, styles, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I want to make a quite complex interface where one ListBox is in another one. First, all elements of ListBox1 get a style "CustomItem" from Style Designer in Firemonkey:

```
  Item := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);
  Item.Parent := ListBox1;
  Item.StyleLookup := 'CustomItem';
```

Then, there is another ListBox ("ListBox2") in the style "CustomItem".

How can I access "StyleLookup" property of this ListBox2?

```
Item.StylesData['ListBox2'].StyleLookup := 'CustomItem2'; //this does not work.
```

Do you know if Firemonkey supports that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood how the [TListBox](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.ListBox.TListBox) component works and how the [StyleLookup](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.ListBox.TListBox) property is involved.
The only control that the TListBox can host is a [TListBoxItem](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.ListBox.TListBoxItem) or a descendant of that control.

the `CustomItem` that you refer to is just a name of the Style Object which is apart of a custom
 FMX style included in the Delphi Firemonkey CustomListBox sample.

You can assign a style object to a specific list box item by providing it's name to the StyleLookup
 property. 
The item will then visually behave as instructed by that Style Object.

What you really are looking for is the [FMX.TTreeView](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.TreeView.TTreeView) component.  You can make it behave exactly like the TListBox with the added bonus of Items being able to host child items.
I suggest you take a good look at the provided Firemonkey sample.

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation! I checked standard examples for FMX.TTreeView and TListBox that Delphi provides together with installation and I agree that my explanation looks like I need TreeView :) But I do need an Item of TListBox that has a lot of other components inside (buttons, comboboxes and another listbox). Yeah, it is a complex interface. I wish I could find a way to access  them, specify a stylelookup and fill with data. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: @Andrey, well yes it's possible. Using the StyleBook you can visually shape each item & subItem in a TTreeView to make it look like it represents an actual FMX object. This is done through the [Firemonkey Style Designer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/FireMonkey_Style_Designer). You create a new TLayout, add for example a TButton on there as a child of the Layout, implement the HitTest and then simply link the name of the TLayout to the StyleLookup property of the TTreeView item that you want to resemble a TButton.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the usage of StylesData, but this can be done with FindStyleResource in the OnApplyStyleLookup event handler.

```
procedure TForm1.ApplyStyleLookupEvent(Sender: TObject);
var O: TFMXObject;
begin
  O := (Sender as TFMXObject).FindStyleResource('ListBox2');
  if O is TStyledControl then
    TStyledControl(O).StyleLookup := 'CustomItem2';
end;
```

You can also put this in your ApplyStyle procedure if you have a custom TListBoxItem object.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer! I tried your code and get a compilation error because variable "O" of type TFMXObject does not have "StyleLookup" property.

I tried to change to this:

var
  SubItem: TListBoxItem;
begin
  SubItem := (Sender as TListBoxItem).FindStyleResource('ListBox2');
  if Assigned(SubItem) then
    SubItem.StyleLookup := 'CustomItem2';
end;

Then I get incompatible types: 'TListBoxItem' and 'TFmxObject'

Comment: @Andrey, you cannot implement a listbox inside a listbox. I've explained that, a TlistBox can only host a TListBoxItem control. You have to look beyond the novelty and realize that a ListBox is essentially a list of strings that are populated in the box as items. You can use the StyleBook to influence how those items appear but you cannot implement other FMX objects as child items. All that this answer shows is how to adopt a style object of a different listbox which has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @Peter, Yeah, now I see what you mean! This makes it clear that it is only appearance of an TListBoxItem that you can change in Firemonkey Style Designer. For example, you can create TLayout where you can have other FMX objects (buttons, edit-fields, etc) in this layout. But as you said, if you apply the layout to a ListBoxItem you still cannot access them as child items of my TListBoxItem. Did I get it right, it is possible to show them, but not use them?

Comment: @Andrey, You can make it appear as if the next item in the listbox is a child item of the previous Item, by padding the text, etc... But that much said the TTreeView already natively supports hierarchical order of items so there is no reason to be faking that in a TListBox component.

Comment: @Peter, In FireMonkey any control can parent any other control. TListBoxItem is such a control. Implementing will be more work, but there is nothing whatsoever to stop you using a TListBoxItem as a parent for a TListBox. This would be best done with a custom descendant of TListBoxItem, and I don't know how it would affext functionality such as scrolling. It's probably creating a monster but it is possible.

Comment: @Andrey, I've added extra typecasts to fix the issue.

Comment: @MikeSutton, you are over generalizing, this is a question regarding a TListBox component. A TListBox component has a specific meaning and specific behaviour. If it would be able to host other controls then it wouldn't be a TListBox component. Trying to implement such behaviour would require you to redesign the whole TListBox control. I never said that it's not possible for controls to parent other controls, that statement by itself is stupid and plays no part here.